# How to fetch cost management in azure subscription using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, subscription

I need to fetch few data related to cost for my azure subscription which are as follows below:

1. Fetch last 6 months cost by service.
   2
   Fetch last 6 months cost by resource group and resources
2. Daily cost of last 15 days.

Pls suggest some useful powershell scripting idea.

I tried using powershell scripting to fetch those details but couldn't able to do so.

I also tried using rest API method, az search graph query and using powershell CMDLETS as well but i am not able to get any appropriate data.

I am expecting evryone to providing me any powershell scripting to fetch those data.

Comment: please share your finding or code which have you tried.

Comment: I expect from someone to share the appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample command.

```
Invoke-AzCostManagementQuery -Scope "/subscriptions/***********" -Timeframe MonthToDate -Type Usage -DatasetGranularity 'Daily'

Column                Row
------                ---
{UsageDate, Currency} {20201101 USD, 20201102 USD, 20201103 USD, 20201104 USD…}
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.costmanagement/invoke-azcostmanagementquery?view=azps-9.1.0

Module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.costmanagement/?view=azps-9.1.0

Comment: Get-AzureCostUsage CMDLETS is not woking.

Comment: @VidhanBhaskar, can you please include the error message?

Comment: how to fetch cost management of in dynamic month for cost_by resourceGroup

Comment: i want to fetch cost by Resource Group of any months. I have written powershell script which is fetching only last 3 (sep,oct & nov) months data. But i want write the script so as to fetch any last months cost.  If i am scheduling the script, then it shows that this is april, may & june or august, sep & oct month, it means it should be dynamic months